# script to find multiples returns "unexpected $end"

Tags: ruby

Does anybody have an idea why this script is not working?

```
def multiples_three (n)
    i=1
    while i<n
        if i%3==0
            print "#{i}"
            i=i+1
        elsif
            i=i+1
end
```

It returns:

```
syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: Ruby isn't Python. As said below, you are missing the closing `end` statements for your `if` blocks. Also, stylistically, Ruby code is written using two spaces for indentation, not four or eight, and definitely not tabs. If your code is never going to be passed to another developer, you can get away with another standard, but if you didn't follow that in our group where I work, you'd hear about it quickly, immediately preceded by howls and gnashing teeth.

Comment: The elsif without a condition is also a problem

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are missing a couple of "end"s in there.

```
def multiples_three (n)
    i=1
    while i<n
        if i%3==0
            print "#{i}"
            i=i+1
        elsif
            i=i+1
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing two "end" statements.

One for the "if"

Another for the "while"

Comment: Thanks a lot!! in fact I tried with two "end", but this one requieres three, I totally missed the def's end!!!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing end

```
def multiples_three (n)
    i=1
    while i<n
        if i%3==0
            print "#{i}"
            i=i+1
        elsif
            i=i+1
        end #<--- needed
    end #<--- also needed
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you were missing some end's... and that bare elsif without a condition bugs me; if you aren't actually testing something, you need an else.

As for styling, you should use two spaces in ruby:

```
def multiples_three(n)
  i=1
  while i<n
    if i % 3 == 0
      print i  # no need to put in string and interpolate if it is by itself
      i=i+1
    else
      i=i+1
    end
  end
end
```

But the more ruby way to do it, woud be to us iterators, ranges, and return an array value instead of printing directly from the function:

```
def multiples_three(n)
  (1..n).select{|i| i % 3==0 }
end

puts multiples_three(12).join("\n")
3
6
9
12
=> nil
```

In fact, ruby makes that so simple, I would never even write that function.